# A series on Stieltjes constants, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\gamma_n}{n!}$, where is the mistake?

Tags: sequences-and-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

[Stieltjes constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) are defined as:

$$\gamma_n=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left[ \left( \sum_{k=1}^m\frac{(\ln k)^n}{k}\right)-\frac{(\ln m)^{n+1}}{n+1}  \right]$$

I want to compute the following series:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\gamma_n}{n!}&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left[ \left( \sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\ln k)^n}{n!~k}\right)-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\ln m)^{n+1}}{n!~(n+1)}  \right]\\
\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left[ \left( \sum_{k=1}^m\frac{e^{\ln(k)}}{k}\right)-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\ln m)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}  \right]\\
\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left[ m-\sum_{p=1}^\infty\frac{(\ln m)^{p}}{p!}  \right]~~~~~~~~~~~(p=n+1)\\
\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left[ m-\left(e^{\ln(m)}-1 \right) \right]\\
\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left[ 1  \right]\\
\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

But the correct answer is $\frac{1}2$...

Comment: In the first equation, you interchange the order of the limits.  That's the very first candidate for an error

Comment: You can use `\to` (or in a different context, `\longrightarrow`) to better render $\to$

Comment: I forget... thank you! @FShrike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn’t say that this is “the” definition of the constants. Much more usefully (to this purpose) they are defined to be the Laurent series coefficients of $\zeta$: $$\zeta(s)=(s-1)^{-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\gamma_n(s-1)^n$$Which, if we evaluate at zero, gives: $$\begin{align}-\frac{1}{2}&=(-1)^{-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\gamma_n(-1)^n\\&=-1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\gamma_n}{n!}\\\therefore\frac{1}{2}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\gamma_n}{n!}\end{align}$$As $\zeta(0)=-1/2$ is known.

As Brian notes, your error was in an unjustified limit interchange.